# I'm trying to scrape data from the at the races website but the scraper is not returning any results

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

from selenium import webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
login_url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/6-October-2018/1715'
driver.get(login_url)
```

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

```
sel_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(sel_soup.findAll("sectionals-time"))
```

When I run the last line of the script it just returns

```
[]
```

It is a dynamic website as far as I am aware, so when you go to this site and scroll down to results, you click the sectional times tab, then right click the first sectional time for the first listed horse and inspect. this then shows me the class attribute as "sectionals-time" so I'm struggling to understand why it's not producing the sectional times for the horses.

Any advice and help much appreciated.

Comment: I found a way. How do you want your output to be? Times per horse or just all the times in a list?

Comment: Hi jxpython, times per horse would be sweet. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. Leave a comment if you need the output to be different.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/6-October-2018/1715'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="racecard-tabs-1061960"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))

# method 1
for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
    horseName = horse.find_element_by_class_name('form-link').text
    times = horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time')
    times = [time.text for time in times]
    print('{}: {}'.format(horseName, times))

print()

# method 2
for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
    for time in horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time'):
        print(time.text)
    print()

driver.close()
```

Comment: jxpython, you are a hero!! Thanks so much man. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh I just noticed you said to leave a comment if I need the output to be different; is it possible to have the horses's name at the start of each row for # method 1 or the top of each list for # method 2, whichever is easier, if it can be done?

Comment: @BrianC No problem! Would you be so kind to accept this answer?

Comment: Hi jxpython, sorry to be a pain, but I was thinking to go to the next race it would mean changing the @id="racecard-tabs-1061960" element of the code, so for next race @id="racecard-tabs-1061961", but it throws an error: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="racecard-tabs-1061961"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)

Comment: Sorry I squeezed that in due to character limit. Of course you solved the main issue and it is very much appreciated and happy to accept it. Just curious as to why the change of Id won't run the code for the next race, as logically, everything else would seem the same?

Comment: Make a new question and I will be glad to help.

Comment: What does next race mean exactly?

Comment: The first race as highlighted in the url is the 17:15, but there are seven more races listed, on the page, 17:15 followed by 17:45, 18:15 and son on. I have now figured out how to get each race. But, at this stage I have to edit the code manually for each race. I'm wondering if I can run a loop to scrape the data for all eight races, without the need to manually change the race ID and url, for the race time. I can post it as a new question if you think this loop is possible. Cheers jxpython.

Comment: Yes I think this is possible. Only if the page looks the same for each of these races/urls

Comment: Thanks. New question posted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have got the selector wrong,
Should you be specifying:

```
soup.findAll("span", {"class": "sectionals-time"})
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, so I changed the specifier to:                                                                               
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll("span", {"class": "sectionals-time"})  but the result is still Out[19]: []